# C++ - confused about const

Tags: c++, constants

I am reading this tutorial about const objects http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/.

I understand const objects can only access const functions. What confuses me is when we pass a const object to a copy constructor, how can it access non-const functions?

Example:

```
class Dog {
     protected:
         string m_name;
         int m_age; 
     public:
         Dog() : m_name("Fido"), m_breed("Corgi"), m_color("Black"), m_age(1) {}
         Dog(const Dog& d) { m_name = d.getName(); m_age = d.getAge(); }
         String getName() { return m_name; }
         int getAge() { return m_age; }
};
```

So when the copy constructor is called with a const dog object, how can this object access the getName() and getAge() functions?

Comment: It can't access non-const functions in that case either. In fact, the default-generated copy-constructor does not call any functions on the object being copied. (although user-written ones might). Do you have a specific code example to illustrate what you are confused about?

Comment: You said it yourself: *const objects* can only access const functions. It's not the const object accessing the non-const functions.

Comment: `const` functions means it has `const` keyword after its header/prototype, not that it has `const` argument

Comment: In the updated code: it can't, this code would fail to compile. You need to mark `getName` and `getAge` as `const`.

Comment: Your question is broken. What is `String`? What is `m_breed`? What is `m_color`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `const` member function is a member function that can't modify the class instance it's being called on.

So if you have a `const` object, you can only call the functions that are declared `const`, by appending `const` after the function prototype:

```
void const_function(int i) const { /* function body */ }
                           ^^^^^
```

That's the *only place* the `const` can appear in, in order to make the function `const`. Other places just modify the return type or the arguments.

---

A [*copy constructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is a just a constructor that takes as an argument a *`const` reference* to an object of the same type. The reference is `const` because the constructor **does not modify** the object passed as the argument, it just *copies from it* and constructs the new object with the copied data:

```
Foo(const Foo& copy_from_this_object) { /* copy member data from argument */ }
```

Also, the copy constructor doesn't actually copy the *`const`ness* from its argument, it just copies all the data from it. I.e. it doesn't matter whether the argument was `const` or not, it's just ***copied***, not ***modified***. The newly constructed *may or may not* be `const`. It has nothing to do with the `const`ness of the copied-from object.

---

***Edit*** (after OP's edit):

> So when the copy constructor is called with a const dog object, how can this object access the getName() and getAge() functions?

It ***cannot***.

This is because the member functions are not properly marked `const` where they should have:

`getName` and `getAge` *don't modify their class instance*. Therefore they should be `const`! After making them `const` they can be called on the `const` object in the copy constructor, and the code will compile fine.

**Note:** In general, you should always make getters `const`. That's because their task should be to only retrieve information about the object, not modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to try compiling your code to see it doesn't work - from [ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/Vy0Ans):

```
prog.cpp: In copy constructor 'Dog::Dog(const Dog&)':
prog.cpp:13:46: error: passing 'const Dog' as 'this' argument of 'std::string Dog::getName()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       Dog(const Dog& d) { m_name = d.getName(); m_age = d.getAge(); }
                                              ^
prog.cpp:13:66: error: passing 'const Dog' as 'this' argument of 'int Dog::getAge()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       Dog(const Dog& d) { m_name = d.getName(); m_age = d.getAge(); }
                                                                  ^
```

You can fix it by making the "get" functions `const`:

```
string getName() const { return m_name; }
int getAge() const { return m_age; }
```

You can see that version compile successfully [here](http://ideone.com/eDIGsh)

Answer (score 0):

**[It *can't*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/841f7954626b938b).**

Try it before asking.